# Simple ?heatmap? of temperature in R (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a simple Date * temperature heatmap (?raster graph?) that shows temperature over time based on binned temperature groups.  Something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_Raster_Plot#mediaviewer/File:Ambient-temperature-ausgburg.png) but only along the date axis (no time variable. I'd prefer to use ggplot, but keep runnning astray. The graph the data produces is headed in the right direction, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the y-axis. I'd appreciate any help

```
dat <- data.frame(temp = sample(20,100, replace=TRUE), date=seq(as.Date("2011-07-01"), by=1, len=100))

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(date, temp)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = temp)) + scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you don't want to map `temp` on the y axis?

Well then you could use a fixed value for y and remove the rest of the y-axis:

```
dat <- data.frame(temp = sample(20,100, replace=TRUE), 
                  date=seq(as.Date("2011-07-01"), by=1, len=100))
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = date, y = 1)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = temp)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could also try doing something like the plot below with the [metvurst](http://metvurst.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/update-to-metvurst/) package.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUoHH.png

```
dat <- data.frame(temp = sample(20,60, replace=TRUE), 
        date=seq(as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 00:00"), by=3600, len=8760))

dat$year <- as.numeric(format(dat$date,"%Y"))

dat$month <- as.numeric(format(dat$date,"%m"))

# Install and load metvurst library
install_github('metvurst', 'tim-salabim')
library(metvurst)

plot.air.temp <- strip(x = dat$temp,
                 date = dat$date,
                 cond = dat$year,
                 arrange = "long",
                 colour = colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"))),
                 main = "Daily Air Temperatures\n\nTemperature [°C]") 

plot.air.temp
```